# PHP read file not working

Tags: php, file, if-statement

I have a problem with my orders. If a person presses F5 too fast, an order can be sent multiple times. I want to write the `order_id` into a file.

Before sending an order and check if the `order_id` is already stored and, if it is, dont send the order again.

I get the `order_id`, than I try to check if it's in the `orders.txt` file. If found in that file redirect to "mysite". If not stored, write it to `orders.txt`.

After the `order_id` is written to `orders.txt` send the `order_id-XXXX.xml` to a URL.

The thing is: only the `else` part works.

If I press F5 multiple times, it writes the `order_id` to the `orders.txt` file each time. It is not checking if it's already there. It also sends the order multiple times.

If I remove the inner `if (file_exists($filename))else{}` part, it works just fine.

Heres my code :

```
$order_id=  $order->get_order_number();
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/xml/order_id-".$order_id.".xml";
$_cassa_point_url='some_url';

$orders_txt = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/xml/orders.txt";

$contents = file_get_contents($orders_txt);
$pattern = preg_quote($order_id, '/');
$pattern = "/^(".$pattern.")/m";

    if( strpos(file_get_contents($orders_txt),$order_id) !== false) {
         header( "refresh:0;url=mysite );
    }else{
        $myfile = file_put_contents($orders_txt, $order_id."\r\n" , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        if (file_exists($filename)) {

            $url = $_cassa_point_url . $order_id;
            file_get_contents($url);
            header( "refresh:0;url=mysite);
            return true;            
        } else {
            $url = $_cassa_point_url . $order_id;
            file_get_contents($url);
            header( "refresh:0;url=mysite );
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using a database for this? Saving order info in plain files isn't a great idea.

Comment: I'm not saving any order info, just a 4 digit number.

Comment: And in "/xml/order_id-".$order_id.".xml"? Anyways I don't really care, it was just a tip. Solutions like this have many problems which is why people generally use a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 header( "refresh:0;url=mysite );
```

you forgot `"` in it so change it to

```
 header( "refresh:0;url=mysite");
```

you have done it in the same way in `else` as well.

Comment: i've just deleted a sensitive site link, and made a mistake, in the actual code it's good.